# Trying to find out, how to skip paying MONTHLY to use PRIVATE PROXYS

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, webproxy

And thanks for reading I will try my best to make it simple.

I pay monthly for 10 proxys on this website.

> *www. squidproxies.com/private-proxies/*
>
> - Number of Proxies: 10 or 100
> - Monthly Price: 24$ or 160$
>
> *(  Because I am a newbie on stackoverflow
>   I don't have enough reputation to post images, I leave you a
>   direct screenshoot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP5MT.png )*

and what I get back from them is a list like this:

> - 168.54.249.1:8800
> - 168.54.249.2:8800
> - 168.54.249.3:8800
> - 168.54.249.4:8800
> - 168.54.249.5:8800
> - 89.45.59.1:8800
> - 89.45.59.2:8800
> - 89.45.59.3:8800
> - 89.45.59.4:8800
>
> ![enter image description here][4] *(Because I am a newbie on stackoverflow
>   I don't have enough reputation to could post images, I leave you a
>   direct screenshoot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xx7L.png )*

My needs are to use 100 FIX PRIVATE PROXYS every month (non-shareable). But I can't afford paying 160$ monthly(I can pay for some hardware if its needed) but want to avoid monthly costs.

So looking around internet I found this:

> 1. (Video) [Create Web Proxy Server - Download and Install Glype] *www. youtube.com/watch?v=2lqHzazSD_0* - YouTube
> 2. (video) [Use Apache Virtual Hosts to serve multiple websites from one server.]*www. youtube.com/watch?v=nslavNYPlbY* - YouTube

Can anybody help me, point a little bit, what direction I should go?
So that i can enjoy 100 FIX PRIVATE PROXYS without having to pay expensive MONTHLY fees.

I want to "do" the same service, "they" are ofering. But by my myself.
How can I create (seems from nowhere) a list with PRIVATE PROXYS and PORTS and use it like am doing now, but going through them?

Thanks in advance,
I hope the answers help other users too!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to go with any vps server

The one i'm currently using is digitalocean vps servers .

I only pay 5 dollars a month for a vps from digitalocean.

https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=f35fb4c85d6a

Here's a $10 coupon - OMGSSD10

Follow list -

1. select  centos 6.5 from there os
2. install Apache with php and mysql
3. set up a self-sign certificate A.K.A SSL
4. upload glype to www/html/
5. done

Remember https is Recommend to surf with proxy

Comment: Seems a really interesting "SOLUTION" :) I gonna try it, and let you know, thanks! :D I love smart guys!! ;)

Comment: Incorrect Promo Code! Sorry, this promo code has expired. 

Where did you find, the coupon discount?

Comment: So this are my 5 questions:
1- Whats the practical difference between x32 and x64 when I select centos 6.5 from there os?
2- How do I install Apache with php and mysql using digitalocean?
3- How do I set up a self-sign certificate A.K.A SSL using digitalocean?
4- How do I upload glype to www/html/ using digitalocean?
5- How do I use https to surf with proxy using digitalocean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another $10 coupon -  SSD2014

DigitalOcean has a forum which can help you out

there no different between 32bit and 64bit cents os